# Query on multiple model (laravel)

Tags: laravel

I hope you guys could understand what I need as result of the below codes.

```
$url = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();

$sectionID = Section::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->first()->toArray();

$categoryID = Category::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->first()->toArray();

$brandID = Brand::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->first()->toArray();
```

```
if (array_key_exists("id", $sectionID)) {

    $productDetails = Product::where(['status' => 1, 'sections_id' => $sectionID['id']])->first()->toArray();

    $totalCountProduct = count($productDetails);


} else if (array_key_exists("id", $categoryID)) {

    $productDetails = Product::where(['status' => 1, 'categories_id' => $categoryID['id']])->first()->toArray();

    $totalCountProduct = count($productDetails);

} else if (array_key_exists("id", $brandID)) {

    $productDetails = Product::where(['status' => 1, 'brands_id' => $brandID['id']])->first()->toArray();

    $totalCountProduct = count($productDetails);

} else {

    $totalCountProduct = 0;

}
```

Comment: We don't, please make a few sentences to explain your problem

Comment: A single sentence followed by that much code is usually an indication that your question is going to be completely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$url = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();

$section = Section::select('id')->where('url', $url)->first();

if ($section) {
    return Product::where(['status' => 1, 'sections_id' => $section->id])->count();
}

$category = Category::select('id')->where('url', $url)->first();

if ($category) {
    return Product::where(['status' => 1, 'categories_id' => $category->id])->count();
}

$brand = Brand::select('id')->where('url', $url)->first();

if ($brand) {
    return Product::where(['status' => 1, 'brands_id' => $brand->id])->count();
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the below code which is working fine for me.

```
$url = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();

$sectionID = Section::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();

$categoryID = Category::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();

$brandID = Brand::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();

if (array_key_exists("0", $sectionID)) {

    $productDetails = Product::where(['status' => 1, 'sections_id' => $sectionID['0']])->get()->toArray();

    $totalCountProduct = count($productDetails);

} else if (array_key_exists("0", $categoryID)) {

    $productDetails = Product::where(['status' => 1, 'categories_id' => $categoryID['0']])->get()->toArray();

    $totalCountProduct = count($productDetails);

} else if (array_key_exists("0", $brandID)) {

    $productDetails = Product::where(['status' => 1, 'brands_id' => $brandID['0']])->get()->toArray();

    $totalCountProduct = count($productDetails);

} else {

    $totalCountProduct = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*First of all* you didn't tell us on which step you're getting error?

*Second thing* I'm supposing you are getting perfect result on following queries:

```
$url = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();

$sectionID = Section::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->first()-toArray();

$categoryID = Category::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->first()-toArray();

$brandID = Brand::select('id', 'url')->where('url', $url)->first()->toArray();
```

#### Product count query:

```
$totalCountProduct = Product::where('status', 1)

->when(!empty($sectionID['id']) && $sectionID['id'], function($q){
   $q->where('sections_id', $sectionID['id']);
})

->when(!empty($categoryID['id']) && $categoryID['id'], function($q){
   $q->where('categories_id', $categoryID['id']);
})

->when(!empty($brandID['id']) && $brandID['id'], function($q){
   $q->where('brands_id', $brandID['id']);
})

->count();
```

By this way you can add `multiple conditions in single` query. and `count()` clause is performance optimize it'll directly instruct `mysql` to get only count of `products`.

In your `get()` clause case, it will scan full table and multple model will be fetched. When the size of your table increased it'll get slower and slower.